# why can't I put any components on the navigation bar or on the status bar

Tags: java, android, xml, statusbar, navigationbar

all details
I wanted to make a fully transparent navigation bar and status bar, and found this article https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-going-edge-to-edge-812f62e4e83e

but i ran into a problem i can't display anything next to nav bar or status bar
it looks like this :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nurfc.png)

xml code :

`

```
<item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast">false</item>
<item name="android:enforceStatusBarContrast">false</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

`
java code :

`

```
Window w = getWindow();
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(w, false);
```

`

What is the problem ? I do not understand :(

googled and wrote a question on stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything is fine with the code, check if you don't have

```
android:fitsSystemWindows = true
```

in your layout